# Syntax error in python when using {} to reference a variable earlier in code

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

Here is my code:

```
    name = input("What's your name? ")
    age = input("how old are you? ")
    age_in_dog_years = age * 7

    print(f"{name}you are {age_in_dog_years}in dog years.")
```

The error I get is:

```
    File "input.py", line 7
    print(f"{name} you are {age_in_dog_years} in dog years.")
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

can't seem to understand the rror

Comment: String interpolation is only available in Python 3.6 and later. What version are you using?

Comment: Also, please format your code by indenting it by four spaces, or highlighting the code and pressing ctrl+k.

Comment: thanks I was on 3.5